# How do I remove the line of TextArea where caret is located

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

what I tried to do is if when I call the function then the line disappeared where caret is located in JTextArea. I achieved at first line case but hard to do in middle and last line cases.

This is perfectly failed code what I did.

```
private void DeleteOptionActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String[] lines = area.getText().split("\n");
    int caret = area.getCaretPosition();
    int beforeLocation = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < area.getLineCount(); i++) {
        try {
            if(i == 0) {
                if(caret <= lines[i].length()) 
                    area.replaceRange(null, area.getLineStartOffset(i), area.getLineEndOffset(i));
            }
            else {
                if(caret <= lines[i].length() && caret > lines[beforeLocation].length()) {
                    area.replaceRange(null, area.getLineStartOffset(i), area.getLineEndOffset(i));
                }
                else {
                    caret -= lines[i].length();
                    beforeLocation = i;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        } catch(BadLocationException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        caret -= lines[i].length();
        beforeLocation = i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `Utilities` class.

No need for any looping logic. Code should be something like:

```
int offset = textArea.getCaretPosition();
int start = Utilities.getRowStart(...);
int end = Utilities.getRowEnd(...);
textArea.replaceRange("", start, end);
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot :)